# Flask-WTF show error message: "The CSRF tokens do not match."

Tags: javascript, flask, flask-wtforms, csrf-token

This the error message I got when I submit empty fields (which is behave like I want in my class form validators):

[image: Empty submit field]

But when I try to submit with valid email, it give me this error message:

[image: Valid email input give csrf token error]

I basically want to submit a form using Flask-WTF but handling it from Javascript `fetch`. Because I want to perform it dynamically like New York Times Login Form: [NYT Login Form](https://myaccount.nytimes.com/auth/login?response_type=cookie&client_id=vi&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2Fsubscription%2Fonboarding-offer%3FcampaignId%3D7JFJX%26EXIT_URI%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.nytimes.com%252F&asset=masthead)

App.py

```
import os

from flask import Flask, jsonify, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session
from flask_api import status
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired

from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash

from helpers import login_required


# Configure flask application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Configure Secret Key
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "secret123"

# Create Form Class
class AuthenticationForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email Address', [InputRequired(message="Please enter your email address")])


# Ensure templates are auto-reloaded
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True

# Configure session to use filesystem (instead of signed cookies)
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

# Configure SQLAlchemy databases
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///" + os.path.join(basedir, 'newspaper.db')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Create SQLAlchemy object of class
class Readers(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
    hash = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Readers {self.email}>'


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    """Ensure responses aren't cached"""
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Expires"] = 0
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    return response


@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():
    """Show Newspaper"""
    return redirect('/auth/login')


@app.route("/auth/<authentication>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def auth(authentication):
    """Log user in"""

    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # Get form class
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    
    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":

        if authentication == 'login':
     
            if form.validate():
                
                data = request.get_json()
                email = data["email"]

                # Check if email already registered in database
                user = Readers.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
                if not user:
                    return "Not Registered Yet", 200
                return "Valid!", 200
  
            return jsonify(form.errors), 400

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    return render_template("auth.html", form=form)
```

auth.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %} 
    Login -  
{% endblock %}

{% block main %} 
    <div class="auth__form-wrapper">
        <div class="auth__title">
            <h2>Log in or create an account</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="success-message"></div>
        <form id="form" method="post">
            {{ form.csrf_token }}
            <fieldset type="email" class="mb-1">
                {{ form.email.label }}
                {{ form.email(autocomplete="off", autofocus=true, required=false) }}
            </fieldset>

            <div id="error-message">
                <span style="color: #cf0000;" id="error"></span>
            </div>  

            <button id="continue" class="btn btn-dark">Continue</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='authentication.js')}}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

.js file to handling submit:

```
const form = document.querySelector('#form');
const successMessage = document.querySelector('#success-message');
const errorMessage = document.querySelector('#error');
const fields = {
    csrf_token: {
        input: document.querySelector('#csrf_token')
    },
    email: {
        input: document.querySelector('#email')
    }
}

form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch('/auth/login', {
        'method': 'POST',
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        'body': JSON.stringify({
            'csrf_token': fields.csrf_token.input.value,
            'email': fields.email.input.value
        })
    });
    if (response.ok) {
        successMessage.innerHTML = await response.text();
    } else {
        const err = await response.json();
        Object.keys(err).forEach((key) => {
            errorMessage.innerHTML = err[key][0];
         });
    }
})
```

If I just use a traditional way instead of Javascript `fetch` to validate Flask-WTForm using `validate_on_submit()` it perform good. Because `validate_on_submit()` seems like handle all validators.

But I just don't know why this happen. Should I use Javascript to handle Flask WTF like my code above? Or I just use Flask WTF using validate_on_submit()? I just want to make a login form that behave like New York Times Login Form: [NYT Login Form](https://myaccount.nytimes.com/auth/login?response_type=cookie&client_id=vi&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2Fsubscription%2Fonboarding-offer%3FcampaignId%3D7JFJX%26EXIT_URI%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.nytimes.com%252F&asset=masthead)

I'm still new on this. I hope you guys can help.

Comment: Instead of setting the csrf token as a field in the body have you tried setting it on the fetch request header? i.e. `headers: {"Content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8", 'X-CSRF-TOKEN':fields.csrf_token.input.value}`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately and fortunately, to make your form look like that of the NYTimes, you need to add JavaScript to your application. Flask cannot add front-end behaviour like that.

And more importantly, if you want to add the csrf-token to the asynchronous request, you could do this:

```html
let form = document.getElementById('#form');
let formData = new FormData(form);
let csrfToken = form.elements.csrf_token.value; 

//add this to your header
'X-CSRF-TOKEN': formData.get('csrf_token')

//OR this
'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken
```

In addition, the asynchronous request in your JavaScript does not validate the form. It just sends a simple POST request asynchronously to the backend route on Flask.
I think it's better that way. Client-side validation does not sound like a safe thing to do. The validation in your code seems okay.